# Linked Javascript file not showing in the Scripts Documents folder

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I have a javascript file that I have in another project that I have linked into my current project.  The linked file shows up just fine in Visual Studio with the correct edits, however, when I clean, compile, and run the project, the [dynamic] file is still showing up.  I have deleted the scripts file in my project, removed the linked file and re-added it, tried in both Chrome and in IE and the file is still pulling in the wrong dynamic file in the scripts document, I have cleared the cache in the browsers.  Anyone have any other suggestions?  I am using VS 2013.

Thanks.

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this answer that fixed my problem:

In internet explorer, go to tools, general, browsing history, settings, change the Check for newer versions of stored pages from automatically to Every time I visit the webpage forced the new script to load.